# TextBox Bind while using DataTemplate MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to bind data with Textbox in DataTemplate. but i am not getting and setting value of textbox property which i have assign to textbox. In out of DataTemplate Textbox property is called where i doing wrong or missing?

**I am trying to using this code in my XAML PAGE:**

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxDataTemplate">
            <Grid  MinHeight="25">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxData" Text="{Binding Path=TextboxDataProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

**and In my ViewModel Page I write following Code:**

```
 public string _objTextData = string.Empty;
        public string TextboxDataProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _objTextData;
            }
            set
            {
                _objTextData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TextboxDataProperty");

            }

        }
```

please inform me at where i have doing wrong.

Comment: How did you set the DataContext?

Comment: no need to give DataContext because out of DataTemplate it is working

Comment: Try out `Text="{Binding}"` and see what is in DataContext, post please here

Comment: @sll DataContext comes null. I bind comboBox using `CollectionViewSource` It is successful. Then how should I bind TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

Create ViewModel in Resources and do the following:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxData" Text="{Binding TextboxDataProperty, Source={StaticResource viewModel}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```